# Close a Terminator terminal opened from bash when the program in it exits

Tags: bash, terminator

I have a udev rule that calls a script whenever I insert a certain USB device. That script launches a terminal using the following command:

```
terminator -e "...some_program" & exit
```

(Could have also been xterm, doesn't matter as far as I can tell.)

Once 'some_program' finishes doing what it should, it exits (from inside that program, not the bash), but the terminator terminal remains open, unless I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it, in which case it closes. But I don't want to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it, that's the whole point.

I have another udev rule that operates when the USB device is removed. But that rule won't trigger until the terminal that was opened from the 
'insert usb rule' closes (even though I used `& exit` after launching the script from the 'insert usb rule')

I don't have anymore ideas and I've searched high and low for a solution. But nothing worked.

- I tried sending SIGINT from inside some_program instead of using exit(1), it didn't work. The program terminated, but the terminal stayed open.
- I tried killing the terminal by getting its PID and killing it. It didn't work.
- I tried opening another terminal and killing the PID from there, it didn't work.

Comment: Some terminals will do this automatically. It's a `terminator`-specific question more than a bash question. (Are you willing to consider other terminals?)

Comment: have you already tried indirectly opening your script from a bash like this: terminator -e "bash -c 'yourCommand'"? maybe this prevents your terminal to open a shell itself and ends the terminal when the shell closes.

Comment: How do you have the `exit_action` option set in your Terminator config file?

Comment: I dont have it set, so i guess its set to default setting.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
terminator -e "bash -c 'yourcommand'"
```

At least when I call ls this way it automatically closes:

```
# this closes automatically:
terminator -e "bash -c 'ls'"
# to test, this closes when the less command is ended (eg. by hitting q):
terminator -e "bash -c 'ls | less'"
```

Apparently terminator doesn't initialize it's own shell this way and as soon as the command passed with the -c option ends, the shell is terminated and terminator automatically closes the window.

Comment: I don't see why this should make a difference. Now `bash` is the `somecommand` that he's executing, and when it finishes his window won't close.

Comment: Yes your right, bash is the somecommand. For me this worked with terminator, but for me also the direct start works, so something is different on his system, or his script does not terminate properly. I'd at least suggest to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks jottbe. I tried your suggestion, I guess something is different about my system. i tried your example and got this: "** (terminator:2940): WARNING **: Binding '<Shift><Control><Alt>a' failed!
Unable to bind hide_window key, another instance/window has it.
PluginRegistry::load_plugins: Importing plugin __init__.py failed: 'module' object has no attribute 'AVAILABLE'" AND if i try with my 'some_program' which is actualy a ros program, then the terminator opens and closes immediately. same with xterm.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. no need use 'bash -c'.
'some_program' is a ROS node, so all i needed to do is kill the rosmaster...

$ killall -9 rosmaster

and it works now.